# RNeo4J connection with R error 403

Tags: neo4j, r-neo4j

hi anybody tried to connect R to Neo4J? When using code:

`graph <- startGraph(url ="http://xxx.x.x:7474/browser/", 
                    username = "neo4j",
                    password = "password")`

I get error : 
*No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
Error: Client error: (403) Forbidden*

Is this related to Neo4J browser? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an invalid URL. You should point to `http://xxx.x.x:7474/db/data/` (and not to the Neo4j Browser endpoint). Try:

```
graph <- startGraph(url ="http://xxx.x.x:7474/db/data/", 
                    username = "neo4j",
                    password = "password")
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using now: 

```graph <- startGraph(url = "http://xxx.x.x.x:7474/db/data/", username = "neo4j", password = "password") still getting the same error.